# GPS in j2me enabled mobiles

Tags: java-me, gps

Does every j2me enabled mobile have GPS service so that the developer can locate its latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because a phone can run J2ME it does not mean that it's manufacturer placed a GPS unit in it. As far as I know there are mobiles which can run Java applications but do not have a built in GPS. If you want to find the location of your phone, you can resort to [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation), where you use cell towers to locate the phone. That being said, this method offers at best, a relatively large margin of error.

If the triangulation mechanism does not work for you, you will have to restrict your application only to GPS enabled phones.