# Can I fetch position of mobile device in j2me having no GPS service using information from cell tower

Tags: mobile, java-me, gps, jsr179

Can I get a location of mobile devices from j2me programming having no GPS unit installed?

Can I obtain the location using cell tower info? I [heard about triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820133/839601) method.

And gone through http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/ doc

In this doc they have given code only for mobile phones having GPS application installed.

But what about the others which does not have GPS in them? How can they get the location?

**update** I got a link which answers my question: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/adding-location-a-non-gps-phone-introducing-cellid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ID of the nearest cell tower to you. The way this is fetched however differs from manufacturers. On Nokia phones, you can get it through something like these:

```
cellID   = System.getProperty("Cell-ID");
if (cellID == null)
    cellID   = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid");
```

while on Sony Ericsson, you have this:

```
System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cellid");
```

Once you get the cell id, you can easily use the [OpencellID API](http://www.opencellid.org/api) to retrieve more information (coordinates, and all that) about the id. The two challenge with this though is that

1. Cell ids may not be accurate to a distance of up to a km
2. The information may not be available on opencellid.org

Comment: You mean to say once one gets the cell id of the particular mobile device ... than one can query for the location of the mobile device with reference to that particular cell 

 If yes ... can you provide me link or code for the same