# How can one acquire position in Non-Gps devices using j2me coding

Tags: networking, java-me, gps

I know GPS technology is used to acquire postion but then how does one can aquire position in Non - GPS devices ? I heard about AGPS or Assisted GPS are there in any other technologies through which one can locate a position ?

(Most prefarable would be Nokia devices)

Comment: already discussed here 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835652/does-getting-a-cell-id-of-mobile-device-will-work-to-get-accurate-posiiton-of-mo/9836129#9836129



baba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On those phones where you do not have a GPS chip you can still get a location using the following:

MCC: Mobile Country Code

MNC: Mobile Network Code

LAC: Local Area Code

CellID

Unfortunately there is no standard way to get these values and different vendors have different System properties. You can see this at http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589

After you get these values you can fetch a lat/lon aproximation from services like http://www.opencellid.org/cell/list

Comment: can i apply the above answer for Nokia enabled Non - Gps phones too

Comment: Great list But then how could i query for lat/ lon from http://www.opencellid.org/cell/list through J2ME code??

Comment: First you must sign to get an API key. Then you can use the URLs described at http://www.opencellid.org/api