# Get Cell-ID in J2ME Application

Tags: java-me, cellid, java-wireless-toolkit

I want a common(generic) code which gives cell ID of the mobile network.

For nokia it is:

```
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid");
```

but I need code which gives cell ID irrespective of mobile vendors.
I used `System.getProperty("Cell-ID");` but this is Giving null to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to get these values and different vendors have different System properties. You can see this at http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589

Similar question at [How can one acquire position in Non-Gps devices using j2me coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927264/how-can-one-acquire-position-in-non-gps-devices-using-j2me-coding)

Comment: Hi, i am using this code http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589 to get the CELL-ID but every time it is giving me null value, please tell me what should i do?

Comment: I am using Nokia Asha 502 . I am getting null values . Please send me any code to get device id.

Comment: What properties have you tried so far? Is your jar file signed?